# Is there any way to render custom symbols with gdx-freetype?

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, game-engine

I want to draw symbols u2680-u2685, but when one of the fields gets a string with one of that symbols, it renders everything, except this symbol.

I know one solution to this problem `FreeTypeFontParameter` has field `characters`. And every symbol from this string will be rendered properly.
But in this case, I need to put ALL Latin symbols and all other symbols in this string one at a time. This is not cool.

Anyone know the better solution to this problem? Maybe without `characters`, or with auto putting range of symbols to this string.

Comment: "But in this case I need to put ALL latin symbols and all other symbols in this string one at a time". Could you elaborate? Why do you need to put ALL latun symbols and other symbols to `characters`? Why don't you just add only symbols, that you need. And what do you mean by adding one at a time?

Comment: @Arctic45 because I use this font to render normal text AND custom unicode symbols.
If I put only this 5 symbols in string, then all other symbols will be drawn with default font.

One at a time for me is adding one symbol by one keyboard button click. Like this: "abcdefg..."

Comment: You could use `FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS`. `characters` =  `FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS` + string of your symbols.